# How to set retention policies on influxdb docker container using entrypoint script in dockerfile

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, influxdb, telegraf

I have created a dockerfile on which i have written telegraf and influxdb instalation and configuration. when i created image from dockerfile and run container, i am getting data from telegraf to influxdb telegraf database.

But when I am trying to set retention policies for telegraf database in influxdb using entrypoint script in dockerfile.  the polcies are not set on the docker container.

I used below commands in script but nothing is worked.

curl -G "http://localhost:8086/query" --data-urlencode "q=CREATE RETENTION POLICY m5 ON telegraf DURATION 1d REPLICATION 1

curl -XPOST "http://localhost:8086/query" --data-urlencode "q=CREATE DATABASE mydb"

influx -port 8086 -execute "CREATE RETENTION POLICY mypolicy1 ON telegraf DURATION 10d REPLICATION 1 DEFAULT"

How to run influx commands from entrypoint script which reflects on docker container?.
Can any body help me on this..

Answer (score 1):

If you are on the host machine use commands below, otherwise replace 'localhost' with your influxdb address and port.

Database creation:

```
curl -i -XPOST http://localhost:8086/query --data-urlencode "q=CREATE DATABASE mydb"
```

Retention policy:

```
curl -i -XPOST http://localhost:8086/query --data-urlencode "q=CREATE RETENTION POLICY "one_week_only" ON "mydb" DURATION 1w REPLICATION 1 DEFAULT"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider running a script in influxdb in order to do that.

The InfluxDB image supports running arbitrary initialization scripts after initial system setup, on both the setup and upgrade paths. Scripts must have extension .sh and be mounted inside of the **/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d** directory. When multiple scripts are present, they will be executed in lexical sort order by name.